BNNS: Why can't I generate random numbers?
I tried to use BNNS Random Generator and print some random numbers for the experiment but I only get 0.0 for some reason.
struct TrainingSample {
    static var randomGenerator: BNNS.RandomGenerator = {
        guard let rng = BNNS.RandomGenerator(method: .aesCtr) else {
            fatalError("Unable to create `RandomGenerator`.")
        }
        return rng
    }()

    static func testExample() {
        var descriptor = BNNSNDArrayDescriptor.allocateUninitialized(
            scalarType: Float.self,
            shape: .vector(1, stride: 1))
        while(true) {
            if #available(macOS 13.0, *) {
                BNNSRandomFillNormalFloat(&randomGenerator,
                                          &descriptor,
                                          0,
                                          2)
                print(" \(descriptor.makeArray(of: Float.self)![0])")
            }
        }
    }
}


Apparently you need to call the "C" function since the namespace version generator isn't compatible - might add answer later.
